# Beginner at Common Lisp: Macro Question For Defining Packages on the Fly

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

Still struggling to understand what best practices are with respect to macros.  I'm attempting to write a macro which defines packages on the fly.

```
(defmacro def-dynamic-package (name)
  `(defpackage ,(intern (string-upcase name) "KEYWORD")
     (:use :common-lisp)))
```

This works fine only for expressions such as:

```
(def-dynamic-package "helloworld")
```

But fails miserably for something like this:

```
(defun make-package-from-path (path)
  (def-dynamic-package (pathname-name path)))
```

or

```
(defun make-package-from-path (path)
  (let ((filename (pathname-path)))
     (def-dynamic-package filename)))
```

I understand how most basic macros work but how to implement this one escapes me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**defpackage** is a macro.  As such, it's expanded at compile-time, not run-time.  What you want is something that is called at run-time in order to make a new package.  Therefore, **defpackage** can't do anything for you.

Fortunately, there's also **[make-package](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_pkg.htm#make-package)**, which provides **defpackage**'s features as a function.  Use it instead of **defpackage**.

Comment: Ah, this was one of the issues I had designing a macro, that defpackage itself was a macro was making it difficult for me to reason about a good approach.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it's defpackage that provides make-package's features as a handy macro. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Failure is to be expected here, because a macro is used when its argument should not be evaluated.

In your first make-package-from-path, the def-dynamic-package will receive as argument a list that is EQUAL to the value of the following expression:

```
(list 'pathname-name 'path)
```

In your case, you only want a function:

```
(defun def-dynamic-package (name)
  (defpackage (string-upcase name)
    (:use :common-lisp)))
```

BTW, if you check the [CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm), you'll see that the first argument of [defpackage](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpkg.htm) needn't be a symbol, but any [string designator](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#string_designator).

Comment: Thanks much, I've had the feeling that learning Common Lisp is a lot about learning when to and when not to use macros.

Comment: What you're doing there is defining a package called “(STRING-UPCASE NAME)” -- at least that would be what you were doing if a list were a valid string designator.  In any case, your code doesn't portably work.

Comment: A couple of issues: a) def* usually names macros and b) see Matthias' answer where he mentions MAKE-PACKAGE. (Your function doesn't work because DEFPACKAGE doesn't evaluate its first argument.

Comment: Ha, crap. I didn't copy-pasted my working code... I always tell people that's the reason you always run actual code and then copy-paste it.